# creating an infinite scrolling background

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I am creating an infinite scrolling background for a game that I am creating. when I run it it scrolls vertically. How would I get it to scroll horizontally? This is the code that makes it scroll.

```
override func update(currentTime: NSTimeInterval) {

    background.position = CGPoint(x: background.position.x - 4, y: background.position.y)
    background2.position = CGPoint(x: background2.position.x - 4, y: background2.position.y)

    //this creates an infinte scrolling background
    if (background.position.x < -background.size.width) {
        background.position = CGPointMake(background2.position.x + background2.size.width, background.position.y)
        }

    if (background2.position.x < -background2.size.width) {
        background2.position = CGPointMake(background.position.x + background.size.width, background2.position.y)
    }
```

}

Answer (score 0):

This is making the .x lessen by 4 on each pass

```
background.position = CGPoint(x: background.position.x - 4, y: background.position.y)
    background2.position = CGPoint(x: background2.position.x - 4, y: background2.position.y)
```

Move that increment to the .y

```
background.position = CGPoint(x: background.position.x, y: background.position.y-4)
    background2.position = CGPoint(x: background2.position.x, y: background2.position.y-4)
```

As an extra bonus....  If you want to achieve a sort of paralax effect, you should use a slower increment on the background that is in the back.

Comment: thank you this solved my problem and okay I will do that

Comment: i got it to work horizontally but when it gets to the top, it stops. How do i get it to keep going.

Comment: Usually you have to incorporate some sort of reset.  So when the .y value equals a certain amount, it's gone far enough, so you set it back to the value at which it started.  So, if it started at y=1000 and y is now 0, set it back to 1000.

Comment: oh okay i understand @durbnpoisn

Answer (score 0):

background.position = CGPointMake(0.0,0.0);